# Notation for function $ + \rightarrow \times $

Tags: notation, tetration, hyperoperation

Is there a standard notation to represent the function building the
multiplication from the addition (I'm talking of the usual $+$ on $\Bbb N$)?

I'm tempted by:
$$ 
x \times y = + ^ y (x)
$$

With such a notation I'd like to write:
$$
x ^ y = \times ^ y (x)
$$

Is there any standard notation to represent this building relationship:
$$
\epsilon: + \rightarrow \times
$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration may be helpful

Comment: It only makes sense for natural numbers, so it doesn't really have to do with abstract algebra as such. In any event, I'd call it iteration and denote it by $x (\epsilon f) y=f^y(x)$. Why do you ask? Also, there's [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Moser_notation), you might be interested in that, and possibly [Steinhaus' notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Moser_notation).

Comment: → Tomasz: thank you. One URL for Knuth's up-arrow notation is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation .

Answer (score 2):

> *This is not a complete answer*

This relation can be formalized as *definition by recursion*:

if we can create an infinite sequence of binary operation on $\Bbb N$ in this way:

First we define $+_1:=+$

we can define $+_{k+1}$ from $+_{k}$ using the recursion over naturals with three steps.

> $i)\,\,\,\, m +_{k+1} 0= b_{k+1}$
>
> $ii)\,\,\,\, m +_{k+1}(n+1)=m+_k (m +_{k+1}n)$
>
> $iii)\,\,\,\, b_ {n+1}:= \begin{cases} b,  & \text{if $n=0$} \\ 0, &
> > \text{if $n=1$ }  \\ 1, & \text{if $n\gt 1$ }  \\ \end{cases}$

In this way we can go from $+_{k}$ to $+_{k+1}$.

This is the same way we build the Hyperoperations ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation))

> $i)\,\,\,\, H_0(a,b):=S(b)=b+1$
>
> $ii)\,\,\,\,H_{n+1}(a,0):=a_{n+1}$
>
> $iii)\,\,\,\,H_{n+1}(a,b+1):=H_n(a,H_{n+1}(a,b))$
>
> $iv)\,\,\,\, a_ {n+1}:= \begin{cases} a,  & \text{if $n=0$} \\ 0, &
> > \text{if $n=1$ }  \\ 1, & \text{if $n\gt 1$ }  \\ \end{cases}$

---

---

As we can see your $\epsilon$ has this property

> $$\epsilon (+_{k})=+_{k+1}$$

About such $\epsilon$ that in our case it takes a binary operation as a imput and give a binary operation as output but  I never saw it. Instead I saw a similar concept for unary fucntions called Superfunction.

We call $F$ [superfunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfunction) (related with [Abel Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_function)) the solution of the functional equation

$$F(0)=b$$

$$F(n+1)=h(F(n))$$

> **Q** *I don't know if there is a notation for this solution but I am interested to know if there is a standard one.*

I usually write $F$, the solution of this equation, as  $\mathcal S [h]$:
$$F=\mathcal S [h]$$

$$ \mathcal S [h](n+1)=h(\mathcal S [h](n)) $$

because I saw it somewhere but I don't remember where.

So if we use this notation for our operations turning them in to unary functions for a fixed $b$

$f_0(n):=H_0(b,n)=n+1$

$f_k(n):= H_k(b,n)=b +_{k} n$

we can find that $f_{k+1}(n):= H_{k+1}(b,n)=b +_{k+1} n$ is the Superfunction of $f_{k}(n)$

so where $f_1(n)=b +_{1} n=b+ n $ we have

$$\mathcal S [f_1](n)=f_2(n)=b +_{2} n=b\times n $$

and in general

> $$\mathcal S [f_{k}]=f_{k+1} $$

Answer (score 0):

I do not claim that this is good notation, but if you want to use standard notation to express this relationship, you can use
$$x\times y=(\bullet+x)^y(0)
.$$
Others might write $\lambda z.z+x$ instead of $\bullet+x$.

Comment: Dear down-voter, if you do not understand, you can ask, if you have objections, you can voice them.