# Fractional and complex rank hyperoperations

Tags: complex-analysis, arithmetic, hyperoperation

The first hyperoperation $H_1(a, b) = a + b$ is addition, and is defined over the complex numbers. The second hyperoperation $H_2(a, b) = ab$ is multiplication, and is also defined over the complex numbers. The third hyperoperation $H_3(a, b) = a^b$ is exponentiation, and can be analytically extended from the natural numbers to the complex numbers for most complex bases $b$ and exponents $p$. The same is true for tetration $H_4(a, b) = \ ^ab$ and higher-rank hyperoperations.

My quesiton is then can the rank variable be extended to the rational/complex numbers: do there exist fractional-ranked and complex-ranked hyperoperations $H_n(a, b)$, where $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $n \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Sure, take any complex number $b.$ Since $H_n(a,b)$ is well-defined for all integers $a$, we can analytically continue it. The question isn't *whether* there is an analytic continuation; it's a question of whether it is a "correct" continuation or not

Comment: Let $k>1$, then $H_k(1,b) = 1$.

Comment: See also: [Example $x$, $y$ and $z$ values for $x\uparrow^\alpha y=z$ where $\alpha\in \Bbb R-\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1227761/272831)