# What's a simple, natural function that is "halfway" between addition and multiplication?

Tags: arithmetic

> What's a simple, natural function that is "halfway" between addition and multiplication, in some sense? Can you think of a way to make that precise?

$$ x + y  \quad\longrightarrow\quad ? \quad\longrightarrow\quad x \cdot y$$

> Alternatively, what's a very natural curve in $\mathbb R^2$ between $xy=1$ and $x+y=1$?

In polar coordinates, these are
$$r=\frac{1}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}\implies r^2=\frac1{2\cos\theta\sin\theta+1}$$
and
$r^2=\frac1{\cos\theta\sin\theta}$,
so maybe:
$r^2=\frac1{(3/2)\cos\theta\sin\theta+1/4}$
or
$$\frac32 xy+\frac14(x^2+y^2)=1,\quad 6xy+x^2+y^2=4$$
$$(x+y)^2 + 4xy=4,\quad (x+y)^2 = 4(1-xy)$$

Comment: There probably isn't one. Adding stuff is repetition of counting (or repeat use of the successor function); multiplying is repeated adding; exponentiating is repeated multiplication; tetrating is repeat exponentiation; and so on. Not that it necessarily prohibits one from making some sort of intermediary step through some form of generalization, though it's hard for me to guess what exactly we want the generalization to preserve...

Comment: I think this question needs a bit more detail before it can be answered well.

Comment: There is something intermediate between $\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $\sqrt{xy}$ though which is $\operatorname{AGM}(x,y)$, but it seems uneasy to implicit draw level lines for this...

Comment: Alternately there is this discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269643/399263

Comment: Also related. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227761/example-x-y-and-z-values-for-x-uparrow-alpha-y-z-where-alpha-in-bbb

Comment: The "simplest" among your proposals would be $(1-t)(x+y)+txy=1$ with $t\in[0,1]$, but it artificially rejects the "negative" part of the curve at infinity. Approaches with tetration are most subtle.